# jQuery - element is selected by attribute but the index returns value of the elements without attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function check(){
    $('.left').removeClass('left');
    $('.right').removeClass('right');

    $('.item[style*="display: block"]').each(function(index){
        console.log('checking...');
        console.log($(this));
        console.log($(this).index()%2);

        if ($(this).index()%2==0)
            $(this).addClass('left');
        else
            $(this).addClass('right');
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div> 
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div> 
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div> 
<div class="item" style="display:none"></div> 
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
```

So here is my code. It is simply supposed to add `left` and `right` classes to the odd and even elements that have `.item` class and have `display:block`. However the `index()` acts as if I selected all the elements with class `.item` without the attribute selection. Can anybody explain me why and how to fix this?

Comment: I can't understand your problem. What is `attribute`? What is html?

Comment: please share the html also.only jquery is not going to help

Comment: The attribute is [style*="display: block"]'The HTML is <div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>

Comment: @HaykSafaryan edit your code and add it in the question

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zu3Ltqya/ is this meeting your purpose?

Comment: I was making a jsfiddle myself thanks for making it already. Your jsfiddle is exactly describing my problem. My purpose is to make the 5 green as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**filter**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter the required elements. Then use [**each**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over jquery object to match the odd and even

```
function check() {

    $('.left').removeClass('left');
    $('.right').removeClass('right');
    $('.item').filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('display') == 'block';
    }).each(function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        if (index % 2 == 0)
            $(this).addClass('left');
        else
            $(this).addClass('right');
    });
}

check()
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zu3Ltqya/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following instead:

```
function check() {

  // select all elements with the class-name of 'left'
  // or 'right':
  $('.left, .right')
    // from those elements remove the class-names 'left'
    // and 'right' if either or both is present (if
    // neither class is present this generates no errors):
    .removeClass('left right');

  // select all '.item' elements whose 'style' attribute
  // features the string 'display:block'; and iterate
  // over that collection using the anonymous function of
  // the addClass() method:
  $('.item[style*="display:block"]').addClass(function(i){
      // i: the index of the current element in the
      // collection:

      // i%2 return 0 then we return the 'left' class-name
      // to be added; otherwise we return the 'right'
      // class-name to be added:
      return i%2 === 0 ? 'left' : 'right';
  });
}
```

```js
function check() {
  $('.left, .right').removeClass('left right');

  $('.item[style*="display:block"]').addClass(function(i) {
    return i % 2 === 0 ? 'left' : 'right';
  });
}

check();
```

```css
div.left {
  color: limegreen;
}

div.right {
  color: red;
}

div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
```

In plain JavaScript the above is equally possible with the following:

```
function check() {

  // Using Array.from to convert the results of the
  // call to document.querySelectorAll() into an
  // Array:
  Array.from(

    // selecting all '.left' and '.right' elements
    // in the document:
    document.querySelectorAll('.left, .right')

  // using Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over
  // the resulting Array:
  ).forEach(function(el) {
    // 'el': the current element in the Array of elements
    //       over which we're iterating.

    // here we use the Element.classList API to remove both
    // the 'left' and 'right' class-name(s) from all
    // elements (no errors if a class-name isn't present):
    el.classList.remove('left', 'right');
  });
  // As above, to convert an Array-like collection into
  // an Array:
  Array.from(

    // here we select all elements with the class of 'item',
    // which also have the string 'display:block' present
    // in their 'style' attribute-value:
    document.querySelectorAll('.item[style*="display:block"]')

  // iterating over that resulting Array:
  ).forEach(function(el, i) {
    // el: as above, the current element of the Array,
    // i:  the second argument, the index of the
    //     current array-element in the array over
    //     which we're iterating.

    // here we add the class-name 'left', if the remainder
    // of the current index/2 is equal to 0; otherwise
    // we add the 'right' class-name:
    el.classList.add(i % 2 === 0 ? 'left' : 'right');
  });
}

check();
```

```js
function check() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.left, .right')).forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('left', 'right');
  });
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.item[style*="display:block"]')).forEach(function(el, i) {
    el.classList.add(i % 2 === 0 ? 'left' : 'right');
  });
}

check();
```

```css
div.left {
  color: limegreen;
}
div.right {
  color: red;
}
div::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="item" style="display:block"></div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [Remainder (`%`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 0):

Below code will solve your problem.

```
function check(){
    $('.left').removeClass('left');
    $('.right').removeClass('right');

    $('.item[style*="display:block"]').each(function(index){
       if ((index)%2==0)
            $(this).addClass('left');
        else
            $(this).addClass('right');
    });
}
```

If you just want to capture the visible elements, then you can also use the below code.

```
function check() {
    $('.left').removeClass('left');
    $('.right').removeClass('right');

    $('.item:visible').each(function(index){
       if ((index)%2==0)
            $(this).addClass('left');
        else
            $(this).addClass('right');
    });
}
```